# Add dongle to wireless keyboard/ change bluetooth frequency/channel/etc

Tags: wireless-networking, keyboard, bluetooth, dongle, logitech-keyboard

I recently bought a Logitech K380 and unfortunately that I'm working in an environment where there is a lot of bluetooth signals surrounding me and it makes my keyboard bluetooth signal very unstable. The letter is so sticky and repeating like "thhhhiisssssss" and the delay time is very high. I just wonder are there any way that I could change my keyboard bluetooth frequency/channel or add a dongle to my wireless keyboard to make it signal more stable. I'm really bad at this so if there is a way please let me know. Thanks.